# Showing an inequality in vector space.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, vector-spaces, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a normed vector space. We define a linear form $T:E\rightarrow \mathbb R$. Denote $H=\ker(T)$.

- Show that if $T$ is continuous, then $H$ is a closed set.

$H$ is the continuous inverse of a closed set $\{0\}$, hence closed.

- Suppose that $H$ is closed. Let $a\in E$ such that $T(a)=1$. Show that the set $a+H$ is closed and does not contain $0$.

My **guess** is that since the set $\{a\}$ is bounded, and since $H$ is closed in a vector space, which means it's also bounded, gives the result that $a+H$ is closed. As for the $0$, we have for every $y\in a+H$, $T(y)=T(a+x)=T(a)+T(x)=1$. However $T(0)=0\neq1$, so $0\notin a+H$.

- Deduce the existence of $r>0$ such that $B(0,r)\cap(a+H)=\emptyset$.

Since $0\notin a+H$, there exists a neighbourhood $V_0$ of $0$ such that $V_0\cap(a+H)=\emptyset$, hence the existence of an open ball $B(0,r)$ such that $B(0,r)\cap(a+H)=\emptyset$.

- Show that for every $x\in B(0,r)$, we have
  $$|Tx|\leq 1$$

This is where I stopped. I thought of the orthogonal projection but didn't understand how to proceed.

Any help and correction of the answers above will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My guess is that since the set $\{a\}$ is bounded, and since $H$ is closed in a vector space, which means it's also bounded, gives the result that $a+H$ is closed.

No, not at all. First of all, $H$ is a subspace so the only way it can be bounded is that $H=\{0\}$. A non-trivial subspace is never bounded. And, second, being bounded does not imply that it is closed. What happens here is that if $\{a+h_n\}$ is a convergent sequence, say $a+h_n\to x$, then
$$
x-a=\lim_nh_n\in H. 
$$
This can be written as $x\in a+H$, which shows that $a+H$ is closed.

> Show that for every $x\in B(0,r)$ we have $|Tx|\leq1$.

Suppose that $x\in B(0,r)$ and $|Tx|>1$. Let $t=\frac1{Tx}$ and put $y=tx$. Then $$|y|=|t|\,|x|< |t|\,r<r,$$ so $y\in B(0,r)$. And $$T(y-a)=\frac{Tx}{Tx}-1=0,$$ so $y-a\in H$. That is, $y\in B(0,r)\cap (a+H)$, a contradiction.